# How to map x,y pixel to world cordinates

Tags: image-processing, opencv

In my project I am calculating x,y in pixel and Z the distance from the camera in mm. So I want to make use of the depth and calculate the x,y,z.

Can any one tell me how I can do that?

I have the following information:

1. x,y pixel obtained from the image
2. Distance from the camera and the object 
   distance from camera and object keep varying, since am making image from different distances

Comment: do you have a calibrated camera?  And you already know the distance to the object? So you already know Z and you want x and y?

Comment: @hammer yea my problem Z am calculating in mm now I want the x,y w.r.t the distance .

Comment: X,y am getting in pixel from the image, yes camera is calibrated and I have the intrinsic matrix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have x,y in image coordinates, a camera matrix, and z in world coordinates then you need to put your image coordinates into a homogenous vector, multiply by the inverse of the camera matrix, and then by your z_world coordinate.  Something that might not be intuitive at first is that your units in world coordinates do not matter.  After multiplying by the inverse of the camera matrix you have defined the ratio x/z which is unitless.  You give the result units by multiplying by z_world.  You can measure it in mm, inches, miles, whatever and your resulting vector will have the same units.

```
cv::Matx31f world_cord(x_im,y_im,1);         //here measured in pixels
world_cord = camera_matrix.inv()*world_cord; //representing a ratio x/z,y/z
world_cord *= z_world;                       //now x,y,z are measured in units of z_world
```

world_cord now contains x_world,y_world,z_world.

Comment: i wanted to get that x,y in mm, not in pixels . is there any way to convert them using the depth

Comment: that is what this does. x_world and y_world are measured in mm at the end